# Minus a Value from a Sum

Tags: summation, geometric-series

Think I'm being really stupid. I have the following sum:

$\sum\limits_{n=1}^r x^n$

which is close to a geometric series with the limits being $0$ and $r-1$ (ideally I want to be using that form)

I am trying to get to

$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{r-1} x^n$

I have attempted expanding both to find what is missing but I am still stuck.

Would I need to presumably minus something to get to what I am looking for?

Thanks

Lewis

Comment: Of course $\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} x^n = (\sum_{n=1}^r x^n) - x^r + 1$...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^{r-1} x^n &= 1 + x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{r-1} \\
&= 1 + \big(x + x^2 + \ldots + x^{r-1} + x^r\big) - x^r \\
&= 1 + \left(\sum_{n=1}^r x^n\right) - x^r
\end{align}